# Is it a good way to pass data to custom view then execute the function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I created a custom input accessory view, it is the submit button.
However, I need to pass the data to the custom view then execute the further function. It is a good way to do that?

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var phoneTF: SignLogTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailTF: SignLogTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTF: SignLogTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FBBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFieldPreparation()
    }

    func textFieldPreparation(){
        EmailTF.inputAccessoryView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignSubmitBTN", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SignSubmitBTN

        phoneTF.inputAccessoryView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignSubmitBTN", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SignSubmitBTN

        PasswordTF.inputAccessoryView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignSubmitBTN", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SignSubmitBTN
    }
}
```

[image]

I am not sure how to pass the data to the custom view or should I do the `sign up` in the `Outlet Action`?

It is my custom view

```
import UIKit

class SignSubmitBTN: UIView {
    @IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var subBTN: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){}
}
```

If I have to pass data to custom view should I use protocol? If I should use the protocol of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...

I think you are approaching this from the wrong direction. The responsibility of a button should be to tell you that a user has tapped it and nothing more. The button should not be dealing with signing in.

But... you are 90% of the way there here. Just a few more bits to add.

You can update your submit button to include a delegate and use the delegate in your button action...

```
import UIKit

// protocol
protocol SignInButtonDelegate: class {
    func signIn()
}

class SignSubmitBTN: UIView {
    // property for delegate
    weak var delegate: SignInButtonDelegate?        

    @IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // this tells the delegate to sign in
        // it doesn't need to know how that happens
        delegate?.signIn()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var subBTN: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {}
}
```

Then in your view controller you conform to the delegate protocol...

```
extension SignUpViewController: SignInButtonDelegate {
    func signIn() {
        // here you already have access to all the data you need to sign in.
        // you are in the view controller here so just get the text from the username, password, etc...
    }
}
```

And then set the view controller as the delegate...

```
func textFieldPreparation() {
    let signInButton = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignSubmitBTN", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SignSubmitBTN
    signInButton.delegate = self

    // these are properties... they should begin with a lowercase letter
    emailTF.inputAccessoryView = signInButton 
    phoneTF.inputAccessoryView = signInButton 
    passwordTF.inputAccessoryView = signInButton 
}
```

Comment: What you mean is I should create a `UIViewController` for the custom view?

Comment: No, you already have a view controller. The SignUpViewController. And this creates your custom view. So just make the SignUpViewController act as a delegate to the custom view.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some code to explain, I have a little bit confuse of the 'delegate', Thanks

Comment: @nicholaslui added more detail now. Rewritten the answer to give reasoning behind it too.

Comment: Thank you! well explanation. Your answer is clear and simple which makes me learn more about the usage of protocol! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    func loadFromNib() -> SignSubmitBTN {


 let bundle  = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignSubmitBTN", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SignSubmitBTN
                return bundle
            }
```

In your viewcontroller call like below:

```
    let customObj = loadFromNib()
    customObj.dataToGet = "Data to pass"
customObj.delegate = self
    EmailTF.inputAccessoryView = customObj
```

If you want pass data from custom class, You need to use delegate protocol as @Fogmeister suggested.

If you want delegate option

```
    public protocol menuOpen:  class {
        func openMenuAction(selectedValue : String)
    }
    class SignSubmitBTN: UIView {
    open var delegate:menuOpen?
 var dataToGet = ""

    @IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {

self.delegate.openMenuAction("test")

    }
    }
```

Then add delegate method in your VC

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController,menuOpen{ 

    func openMenuAction(selectedValue : String) {
    //get your selected value here, you would better pass parameter in this method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CustomView is just a class at the end, so you can do it in object oriented paratime, For that write a function in your customView to pass data in it. Like

```
   class SignSubmitBTN: UIView {
       var data: String!;
       public func setData(data: String) {
             self.data = data;
       }

       /// Other code
    }
```

And to set data after initializing your CustomView, call setData(params) function to set data in it.